# Html elements with same "top" value appearing in different locations

Tags: html, css

I have an image and a rectangle (a paragraph with a coloured background) that should have their tops line up. They're both absolutely positioned and have the same style-top value, but the top of the rectangle is appearing about 15px below the top of the image, and I can't figure out why. Is there any reason why this might be happening?

HTML:

```
<img class="v1" id="image" src="/COMP2405A4/images/resized_adorkable!.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:313px;left: 61px;" alt = "Your Image">
<p class="mask" id="tmask" style="position:absolute;top:313px;left: 61px;width: 400px;height: 20px"> </p>
```

CSS:

```
p.mask {background: rgb(255,255,255);
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the resulting HTML?

Comment: Please don't show your PHP code. I really doesn't help when trying to fix a client-side problem. Show your HTML OUTPUT instead.

Comment: Does the `<p>` have a margin set on it? Try setting the margin to 0 in the style declaration.

Comment: PHP replaced with HTML. @Pete Just tried setting margin to 0 and it worked - do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Pete is right. He should answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements don't line up because the margins of your elements aren't the same.

Try explicitly setting `margin: 0;` on the `p` element.

Comment: Yep, perfect, thanks. This was definitely a lesson in not assuming that everything defaults to 0/null.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have the right idea. One of your other classes may be throwing you off. I made an example if you want to take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/hwrQA/

Answer (score 0):

It can't be other classes since the relevant styles are applied through a style tag, which overrides the default styles it may have.

However I can theorize that it may have to do with on of the elements, probably the image, having additional styles through the stylesheet creating extra offset.

Like padding on an image, the effect differs per browser but it may create the extra offset.

The best thing you can do to check why the offset it not correct is use the developer tools in chrome or firebug in firefox to select the relevant element and see which styles get applied and where they are coming from. Internet Explorer has debugging tools too but I wouldn't recommend them to start with.

If you want a better answer you're going to have to reproduce it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what is wrong. Try taking away stuff until nothing irrelevant to be bug remains, or if the bug dissapeared in this process you may have solved it yourself. Read the [how to ask faq for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).